# Answering landline calls with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, telephone

How can I connect an Arduino to a phone line such that, when a call rings, the Arduino will 'answer' and be able to respond with (touch) tones and, if possible, 'hear' touch tones as well for 2-way communication? Is it possible to only answer on double rings?

I saw [this page](http://brohogan.blogspot.com/2009/12/telephone-interface.html) on a similar topic, but that does not describe *answering* with an Arduino.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.elektronika.ba/508/phoneline-controller-v2), it's from the comments in the link you provided and seems like it is able to answer calls.

Answer (score 6):

The page you link to references the [Cermetek CH1817-LM](http://www.cermetek.com/catalog/Telephone-Line-Interface/DataSheet/CH1817_607-0007.pdf) Direct Access Arrangement Module. **It provides a simple interrupt pin for Ring Detection**, while handling some of the more complex POTS interfacing. They just didn't implement it.

The rest is simple. You just need a DTMF decoder and encoder.

Actually, the page gives you everything you need, just need to adjust the code for your own use.

Alternatively, you could use some other chips. TI's [TCM1520A RING DETECTOR](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scts005b/scts005b.pdf)
for ring detection. Or take apart a Answering Machine or older isa/pci 56k modems. The older, the bigger the ICs and better documented.

Comment: Why take apart an old modem? Why not just interface directly with it? Google the AT command set, modems can do a lot more than download pornography frustratingly slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an Arduino shield called MICO that can help you with this project. This shield connects to an Arduino and to a cell phone via the audio jack. The shield detects the phone is ringing and can answer the call.

Upon answering the call it presents the user with a voice prompt (audio files are stored in the onboard microSD card). Check it out at [HelloMICO.com](http://HelloMICO.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is an evaluation board called a  CPC5622-EVAL-600R from IXYS.

This card is an eval board for their chips. There is a doc about it at https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/UG-LLIII-EB.pdf/$file/UG-LLIII-EB.pdf

It costs right now about $210 CDN but a group buy could make it cheaper.